# Django Multiple user type

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have different types of users where I have to collect different types of information from different types of users.
Eg:-
if the user is accountant the required information would be id proof;
if the user is executive the required information would be id proof and other personal details;
if the user is client the required information would be official details like Company name, company id, etc.

Please help me out in this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Solution here fits your requirements well - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55372593/6782044

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I got you . This is the problem I have faced a lot while having different types of users in django. For this problem i have creataed a whole article on geeksforgeeks . The way this can be done is using proxy models . Have a deep look , this will definitely help out .

[Article Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-multiple-user-types-and-using-proxy-models-in-python-django/)

When you create proxy models after seeing and understanding the article , you can perform every kind of action on the new model , with creating one to one relation with your new model  , define the pythonic behaviour of the new model .

Like , you created a model accountant you can create one to one relation with model accountantDetails and go further the way you want.
But there will be one limitation that , you cannot create custom field in the new proxy model , but one to one relation will do the work .